# Table Schema inside PIG UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog, udf

I have to format data in a flat file before its getting loaded into Hive table.

```
CF32|4711|00010101Z| +34.883|  98562AS1D |N8594ãä| 00   | 2
```

The file is pipe separated and I need to apply different cleaning and formatting functions on the different columns in the flat file .
I have multiple functions  to Clean_Text, Format_Date, Format_TimeStamp, Format_Integer etc.

My idea is to pass the schema as constructor to my UDF and call the different functions on the flat file in pig.

```
A = LOAD 'call_detail_records'  USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
DESCRIBE A;

REGISTER ZPigUdfs.jar;
DEFINE DFormat com.zna.pig.udf.DataColumnFormatter(A);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE DFormat($0);
DUMP B;
```

But how can I pass the schema ?
DUMP A actually dumps the entire table but I need the metadata only.
 My current UDF pseudo code looks like

public class DataColumnFormatter extends EvalFunc {

```
private Tuple schema;

public DataColumnFormatter(Tuple schema) {
    this.schema = schema;
}

@Override
public String exec(Tuple inputTuple) throws IOException {

    if (inputTuple != null && inputTuple.size() > 0) {
        String inpString = inputTuple.get(0).toString();
        System.out.println(inpString);
        System.out.println(schema);

        /**
         * Logic for splitting the string as pipe and apply functions based
         * on positions of schema if(schema[1] -> date ){
         * 
         * formatDate(input) }else if(schema[1] -> INT ){
         * 
         * formatInt(input); }
         * 
         */

    }

    return null;
}
```

}

How can I get the schema in PIG UDF or is there any alternative way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Where should this schema come from?   
(2) What is holding you from defining the schema as a constant?   
(3) Is it possible that different lines within the same table will have different schema?

Comment: The schema should come from the HCatalog. I have multiple files and I don't want to define schema every time I run the scripts . No all records in a table are having same schema .

Answer (score 1):

From within your EvalFunc you can call `this.getInputSchema()` (at least since Pig v0.12, maybe earlier). You shouldn't need to do anything special to pass in the schema, and since you loaded from HCatalog, `A` will already be decorated.

Alternately, you could consider breaking out separate UDF functions for each data type. Something like `B = FOREACH A GENERATE dateFormat($0), cleanText($1), dateFormat($2);`